# pandas select rows after groupby

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

In DataFrames,

```
 item_#, status, field1, field2 
   123,    "A",    "val1", "val2"
   223,    "B",    "val3", "val4"
   123,    "B",    "val5", "val6"
   323,    "A",    "val7", "val8"
```

what I want is the list of `item_#` that has both status `"A"` and status `"B"`.
something like `df.groupby('item_#')[(df.status.isin(['A', 'B']`), but this doesn't actually work.  It gets me all the item that either one of the values in the list.

any suggestion would be appreciated!

Comment: What is your desired output for this example?

Comment: a new dataframe contains only items that have both status "A" and "B", so in this case, would be a dataframe that contains only item_#['123'] because it has both statuses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can using `filter` + `isin`

```
df.groupby('item_#').filter(lambda x : pd.Series(['A','B']).isin(x['status']).all())
Out[473]: 
   item_# status field1 field2
0     123      A   val1   val2
2     123      B   val5   val6
```

Update method

```
df[df.groupby('item_#').status.transform(lambda x : {'A','B'}.issubset(set(x)))]
   item_# status field1 field2
0       1      A   val1   val2
2       1      B   val5   val6
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `set`:

```
df[df.groupby('item_#')['status']
     .transform(lambda x: set(x.values.tolist()) == {'A','B'})]
```

Output:

item_# status field1 field2

```
0     123      A   val1   val2
2     123      B   val5   val6
```

Comment: When you are declaring a set with known elements, you shouldn't use the `set` keyword. Just use the braces. Also, you can use `filter` like this instead of `transform`. `df.groupby('item_#').filter(lambda x: set(x['status']) >= {'A', 'B'})`.

Comment: @TedPetrou Thanks for the improvement.   I think, in general, filter is slow than transform boolean indexing.

Comment: What about simplify solution - `set(x.values.tolist())` to `set(x)` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use unstack, dropna and stack:

```
df.groupby(['item_#','status']).first().unstack().dropna().stack()
Out[136]: 
                    field1   field2
item_# status                      
123        "A"      "val1"   "val2"
           "B"      "val5"   "val6"
```